# Unity 2D : Placing a tile from an asset/Tile Palette to a Tile Map with a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets, tiles

I am trying to place Tiles by using a script and need to retrieve them from either a tile palette or directly a tile in my asset folder. I can't assign them manually by using a public TileBase because that would make like 50 public Tiles and would be unpracticle.
The best answer would be something like :

```
    TileBase newTile;
    newTile = ???;
```

I tried to fill in with

```
newTile=AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Tiles/water_funnel_1",TileBase);
```

but could't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tile.SetTile(Vector3Int, Tile);
```

Tile must be public, for now i dont know how to do it using the Path in code but this should work.